# Select2 select all elements after opening

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have select2 and need to document.querySelectorAll all items of the select2 after opening.
I can't select them before opening, because the container with items isn't generated before click.
All my select2 items have class select2-item.
I'm trying to handle this by using .on("select2:opening"), but no data will be in my variable.

```
$("#select").on("select2:opening", function(){
   selectAllItems();
});

function selectAllItems(){
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".select2-item");

    console.log(items);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

The output is

```
NodeList []
    length: 0

{}
```

Version of Select2 is 4.0.5.

Comment: What are you trying to select? All `<option>` values of a specific select2 element? For the whole page? The select2 `<li>` elements? It is unclear. Your code above is also broken - `#select` should have quotes around it, and it also doesn't match the query selector your are attempting to retrieve.

Comment: I'm trying to select all ´<li>´ elements in particular select2.

Comment: Hi Daniel, did my answer end up working for you?

Comment: Hello Jason, yes. I marked your answer as solution.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment of wanting all the `<li>` items, you would normally do this inside your `selectAllItems()` function, as the dynamically-generated list is contained within a `<span>` element that has the class `.select2-container`.

```
const items = $('.select2-container li');
```

However, if you call this function immediately on the `select2:opening` event, the list will not have been generated yet. You can instead put in a very small delay of say, **100 ms** which will give enough time for the list to be generated, and then you can select the items within. This should work for you:

```
function selectAllItems() {
  const items = $('.select2-container li');
  console.log('items', items);
}

$(function() {
  $('#select').select2();
  
  $('#select').on('select2:opening', function (e) {
    setTimeout(selectAllItems, 100);
  });
});
```

I tried using the `select2:open` event without a timeout, but that produced a single `<li>` for loading results which isn't correct. Using `select2:open` with the same 100 ms timeout did work though.

I will say that it is unusual to want to work on the list items directly - select2 allows you to work on the original `<select>` list and `<option>` elements and that is what you should strive to interact with. The above code will work for what you asked for, but I would not work on those `<li>` DOM elements individually unless you had a very specific reason.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is that I have this select with many options. I can mark any option as favorite. I have a list, where are filtered all favorite options. And I want to do that when I choose a favorite item in my list, the option select2 will highlight as well as the list item. The opposite way is working - when I select the favorite in select2 - the list item will highligt, but I'm not able to do that this way. Do you have any suggestion to workaround this?

Comment: Still not exactly sure what you mean but did you try my solution? It shows how you can get all the list items when you open the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
$("#select").on("select2:opening", function(){
   let items = $('option:selected', this).val();
    selectAllItems(items);
});

function selectAllItems(items){
    
    console.log(items);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
}
```